# Flutter - Change font size after decimal

Tags: flutter, dart

How to change font size after the decimal point in the Flutter

[image: Like this]

Like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html).

> The RichText widget displays text that uses multiple different styles.